# What's the best way to connect to an external OAuth2.0 endpoint?

Tags: apex, api, oauth2

I am building a API client in Apex that will access a 3rd party GraphQL server. I need to authenticate using a standard OAuth2 process where I provide clientid/secret, username, password... I need to retrieve a token and use it to make calls to the server in my Apex code by adding the token to the Authorization header. I know how to do this using Http.send(HttpRequest) in code.... however I was hoping there might be a more secure/standard fashion using Named Credentials and/or Auth Providers. It's not one of the predefined providers in the list (Google, Facebook, ...) of Auth Providers. How can I accomplish this? Is there a best practice I can follow?

Comment: Does your third-party support OpenID Connect? This is an option in Salesforce, and a lot of providers seem to accept this protocol as an option.

Comment: Unfortunately no - that isn't an option in this case.